# React Native - CameraRoll got issue undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-0.46

I used **[react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker)** for fetch image form camera and photo library. i follow the steps to and link react-native-image-picker in xcode. I will code also to open imagePicker. but have an error.

Note : I will used 0.46 for react native.

Successfully link in iOS and Android.

[image]

My Code :

```
import { ImagePicker } from 'react-native-image-picker'
```

And onButton :

```
handleImagePickUp = () =>{
   ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response)  => {
   });
}
```

Error :

[image]

Comment: Where does this code break? When you press take photo/choose from library, or when calling the method which contains the given function?

Comment: the code break ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing

`import { ImagePicker } from 'react-native-image-picker'`,

you should declare ( In the same place )...

`var ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker');`.

The rest of your code should work, although it's hard to tell since its not provided. Hope this helps, if you dont understand why this must be done let me know.

Comment: ok. thanks it working. but please give me explanation when  import { ImagePicker } from 'react-native-image-picker' and var ImagePicker = require('react-native-image-picker'); is used.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but for this case you never use import for ImagePicker. There was a discussion on it here -> https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1973 . By the way, if you ever have similar problems to this in the future, often looking into the README file in the respective node modules file ( project/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/README.md in this case ) should solve your problems